# EmacsのM-x shellでgit-completion.bashが効かない

Tags: git, emacs

以下の記事を参考に、git-completion.bashとgit-prompt.shを設定しました。

[「Git補完をしらない」「git statusを1日100回は使う」そんなあなたに朗報【git-completionとgit-prompt】](https://qiita.com/varmil/items/9b0aeafa85975474e9b6)

同じ~/.bashrcで、ターミナルのbashと、EmacsでM-x shellで起動する*shell*バッファのbashを共用していますが、git-prompt.shの方は有効になり、プロンプトにブランチ名を表示させることができました。

しかし、git-completion.bashの方はなぜか、ターミナルの方では有効になるものの、Emacsの*shell*では有効になりません。
どうすればEmacsでも有効に出来るでしょうか。

以下は環境です。

Windows 10でWSL1を駆動し、Ubuntuを起動しています。

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"

$ emacs -version
GNU Emacs 26.3
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: shell モードにおいて、TAB or `C-i` が `(completion-at-point)` に bind されていることが原因です(bash process に TAB キー押下のイベントが届いていません)。`term` か `ansi-term` モードを使う方が良いかとは思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ M-x term  を使うと *term* バッファーになりましたが、C-cもC-xも効かなくなりますね。M-x ansi-termを使うとC-cもC-xも効く状態で、gitコマンドも補完するので、これでしばらく使ってみます！

Comment: うーん、やはり*shell*とは大部分使い方が違いますね～。「(global-unset-key "\C-i")」だけして*shell*に戻ってみましたが効かないようでした。

Answer (score 0):

デフォルトのshellはそのままでは対応していないので、こちらを導入すると良いと思います。

https://github.com/szermatt/emacs-bash-completion